# Is there a way to calculate average buy/sell price for stock share without cycles?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

[image: orderbook]

I'm looking a way to calculate average sell\buy price of stock share without cycling through each element (using pandas\numpy functions).

Let's assume I want to sell 100 shares. The topmost levels will be sold first. The average selling price will be calculated like this:

161.58 * 2 = 323.16

161.57 * 1 = 161.57

161.56 * 16 = 2584.96

100 -  (16 + 1 + 2) = 81

161.55 * 81 = 13085.55

323.16 + 161.57 + 2584.96 + 13085.55 = 16155.24

16155.24/100 = 161.5524

So, the average price to sell shares (average ask price) is 161.5524  per share

Same thing for buying shares.

161.61 * 25 = 4040,25

161.62 * 75 = 12121,5

12121,5 + 4040,25 = 16161,75

16161,75/100 = 161,6175

So, the average price to buy shares is 161,6175  per share

The original table is looking like this:

| ask_19_price | ask_19_amount | ... | ask_1_amount | ask_0_price | ask_0_amount | bid_0_price | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 161.42 | 3124 | ... | 1 | 161.58 | 2 | 161.61 | ... |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

The resulting table I'm looking for should look like this:

| ask_avg | bid_avg |
| --- | --- |
| 161.5524 | 161,6175 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a solution given a more "ideal" scheme for the starting dataframe.

(not sure where you are getting your data from, but its not ideal for analysis, of course it can be transformed to the scheme i will be using)

the process shown should work the same for ask / bid

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame(
   ...:     {
   ...:         'ask_number': [0,1,2,3,4],
   ...:         'ask_price': [161.58, 161.57, 161.56, 161.55, 161.54],
   ...:         'ask_amount': [2,1,16,131, 331],
   ...:     }
   ...: )

In [3]: df
Out[3]:
   ask_number  ask_price  ask_amount
0           0     161.58           2
1           1     161.57           1
2           2     161.56          16
3           3     161.55         131
4           4     161.54         331

In [4]: amount = 100
   ...: # Assuming that df is sorted by ask_number...
   ...: # NOTE: can merge first 2 lines into one calculation of "left" - leaving as is to make code and results clearer
   ...: df["ask_amount_cumsum"] = df["ask_amount"].cumsum()
   ...: # Calculate how many stocks are "left" to sell:
   ...: # Fill the first row (NA because of shift) with the original amount
   ...: # Clip 0 - change negative numbers to zero -> so they are ignored later
   ...: df["left"] = (amount - df["ask_amount_cumsum"]).shift(1, fill_value=amount).clip(0)
   ...: # Take minimum between "left" and "ask_amount"
   ...: df["taken"] = df[["left", "ask_amount"]].min(axis=1)
   ...: ask_avg = (df["taken"] * df["ask_price"]).sum() / amount

In [5]: df
Out[5]:
   ask_number  ask_price  ask_amount  ask_amount_cumsum  left  taken
0           0     161.58           2                  2   100      2
1           1     161.57           1                  3    98      1
2           2     161.56          16                 19    97     16
3           3     161.55         131                150    81     81
4           4     161.54         331                481     0      0

In [6]: ask_avg
Out[6]: 161.5524
```